# CakePHP echo first and last record of array output foreach() iteration

Tags: arrays, cakephp, loops, foreach

I am able to access and output a full array list of Zip items like so (this is working as expected):

... (this is a foreach within a foreach)

```
foreach ($plan_edit['Zip'] as $zip) :
    echo $zip['title'] . "<br />";
endforeach; ...
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 110
            [state_id] => 1
            [title] => 97701
            [PlansZip] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 83698
                    [plan_id] => 443
                    [zip_id] => 110
                )

        )

    [1]
```

I am trying to ONLY get the first and last value (of ['title']) of each array set for each main record.

I've been messing around with phps array current() and end() functions, but I can only get "Array
" to print out with those.

I know I am doing something wrong, but kind of lost direction at this point.

Any constructive criticism of my work/methods is welcome.

This is where I am at currently:

```
<?php

foreach ($plan_edit['Zip'] as $zip) :
    echo current($zip['title']) . "<br />";
     endforeach;

foreach ($plan_edit['Zip'] as $zip) :
    echo end($zip['title']) . "<br />";
     endforeach; 

     ?>
```

Comment: What's messing my thought process up is I am trying various ways to do this like: <?php 
foreach ($plan_edit['Zip'] as $key=>$value) :
echo max($value) . "<br />";
endforeach;
?> - but the $value output is "Array" not the actual value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$first = reset($plan_edit['Zip']);
$last = end($plan_edit['Zip']);
echo $first['title'];
echo $last['title'];
```

If the array is numerically indexed, you can also just do:

```
echo $plan_edit['Zip'][0]['title'];
echo $plan_edit['Zip'][count($plan_edit['Zip']) - 1]['title'];
```

Comment: your second suggestion solved the problem. I was trying to work on a solution with the first suggestion, but the array is numeric. Cheers.